# How to create drop shadow?

Tags: html, css

I want to add drop shadow to input fields, I tried this code

```
.inp_text{
background: url(../images/inp_back.png) no-repeat;
border: none;
color: #393939;
height: 34px;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
width: 156px;
}

.inp_text:focus{
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8);
}
```

This is working fine in firefox but, I am not getting the blue glow in other browsers(IE & chrome). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `outline:none;` in `.inp_text` you will find the desire result.

```
.inp_text{
    background: url(../images/inp_back.png) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    color: #393939;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    width: 156px;
    outline:none;
}
```